# Equivalent of getCellType Apache POI 3.15

Tags: apache-poi

getCellType in POI 3.15 is depreciated and i don't see any equivalent for the same in documentation.

Anybody know what method to use to get cell type using the latest version of poi

Regards
Libin Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getCellTypeEnum` method according to the Apache POI [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/EvaluationCell.html). It will return `CellType` which will have following cell types **_NONE, BLANK, BOOLEAN, ERROR, FORMULA, NUMERIC** or **STRING**.

```
_NONE-Unknown type, used to represent a state prior to initialization or the lack of a concrete type.
BLANK-Blank cell type
BOOLEAN-Boolean cell type
ERROR-Error cell type
FORMULA-Formula cell type
NUMERIC-Numeric cell type (whole numbers, fractional numbers, dates)
STRING-String (text) cell type
```